# ionic 4 deal with modal when users click phone back button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

What should happen when users click over back button of phone? In case when modal opens.

Registered a back button:

```js
// To prevent interference with ionic's own backbutton handling
// you can subscribe with a low priority instead
this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
  // code that is executed when the user pressed the back button
  // and ionic doesn't already know what to do (close modals etc...)
  self.modalController.dismiss();
});
```

The problem with the code:

- It closes/dismiss modal is fine!
- But it also pushed back the page from where the modal is opened. Means it pop the page behind modal.

This should not happen the page should not pop - only modal should close.

Check the image gif added ->
[Click here to see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq1ni.jpg)

Comment: At end of code you can try return false;

Comment: Not working! Same problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using `platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority()` with a high priority (ex: 9999).

Then checking if there is a opened modal with `modalController.getTop()`.

```
constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController, private nav: NavController) { 
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(9999, () => {
    this.closeModalOrPage();
  });
}

async closeModalOrPage(){
  let modal = await this.modalCtrl.getTop();
  if (modal){
    modal.dismiss();
  } else {
    this.nav.pop();
  }
}
```